# Was there car insurance in the USSR?

Tags: soviet-union, economy

I can't imagine how it works in a planned economy. Does the government replace your car if you crash it? Was there no sort of insurance?

Comment: Have you done any basic research on the economy of the Soviet Union?  Wage labour, clearing consumer and production goods markets, loans of capital at interest and profit all existed continuously. What didn’t exist was private capitalists. But “the government” was not a singular entity: trusts and boards made capital decisions. Gosplan was barely more of a plan than Keynesian central bank money price planning

Answer (score 11):

Actually, there was a famous Soviet movie from 1966, [Береги́сь автомоби́ля](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beware_of_the_Car), 
 whose plot centers around car insurance: The main character sells car insurance during the day and steals the insured cars at night and, after selling stolen cars, donates the proceeds to orphanages. (No, he is not crazy, he even has a document certifying his sanity.) The movie is quite good (great director and cast of actors), here it is on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ33mMmfvaM).

Edit. On a more serious note, the following info is taken from the book "[Плакат Госстраха](http://rgsmuseum.ru/r/2CCA146C-22ED-4119-85EF-614699C55C3E/RGS_book.pdf)", Moscow, 2012.

All insurance in USSR was done by a monopoly, [Госстрах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0), established in 1921. 
According to the book, the first time (presumably, since 1920s) private cars in USSR were insured (by Госстрах) in 1946, specifically, 99 cars. The number went up to (approx) 1700 by 1949 and to 188500 by 1969.

Below are two Soviet ads for auto-insurance, from 1951 and 1967 respectively. 
Besides cute posters, the book (which is 359 page long) contains more details on personal insurance in the Soviet Union.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**USSR did allow private property over personal-use items, which included cars** and even houses or apartments. What was not allowed was private property over commercial or industrial assets ("means of production"), or private business (they turned a blind eye towards self-employed stuff like tutoring or handyman services)

There was personal insurance in Soviet Union. There was accident and life insurance (often with savings component to it), as well as insurance covering houses and cattle (critical for peasants).

Coverage for vehicle itself seems to have been introduced in the 1980's: [Russian wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0#1971-80-%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B)
Same page implies there was mandatory coverage for passengers
But proper liability insurance was rolled out only after USSR was gone : [Russian wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2)

Comment: The vast majority of USSR history happened before the 1980's. So if it only got it in the 1980's, that's pretty darn close to a "no".

Answer (score 8):

At USSR times, there was so called GosStrakh system (short form of **Gos**udarstvennoe **Strakh**ovanie, aka Government Insurance). From 1946, it started car insurance program as well.

However, as any other insurance company, it had very contradictory reputation.

Comment: +1, this looks like a good start for an answer. Can you expand it and add some links? Also, it looks like car insurance was already there in 1926, there's a [magazine article](https://www.zr.ru/archive/zr/1928/07/za-doroghu-i-mashinu-instruktsiia-vtu#47) from 1928 that mentions it

Answer (score 4):

Cars in the USSR were not government issued, unless they were company cars so to speak, just as in Western countries. You saved up for one, ordered one, and waited until it was delivered. Difference is that the number manufactured was planned, and independent of actual demand, so you would likely have to wait for 5-10 YEARS for delivery.

[Jalopnik](https://jalopnik.com/what-it-was-like-to-buy-and-own-a-car-in-the-ussr-1783136956) is an interesting read, and mentions nothing regarding insurance. Of course that may be an oversight by the author,  but he does mention just going to the black market for spare parts or if your car got stolen, suggesting that insurance, even if it did exist, wasn't really useful (unsurprising, as the planned economy meant that the insurance couldn't simply issue you a replacement for a stolen or wrecked car, you'd have to wait another 10 years).

[Marxist.org](https://www.marxists.org/history/ussr/government/1928/sufds/ch18.htm) mentions "transportation insurance" being available from 1922 but doesn't explain what that entails. This is a transcript of a booklet about the USSR published in 1929 so doesn't really say anything about the later years of the USSR when cars were manufactured locally.

Comment: You definitely didn't need to wait 5-10 years in Hungary (source: my in-laws owned a car back in those days). Maybe add a source that isn't Reagan's famous joke to back that assertion?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy the article listed mentions the author remembering having to wait 7-10 years, matching the Reagan joke. He's asserting that Reagan got it right... Do remember that things were quite different in Hungary from the USSR, especially the economy was a lot more geared towards serving the citizens.

Comment: I dunno if I'm inclined to believe the article's author's "recollection". Judging by his photo, he's around 30 at most, so would have been a young kid when USSR collapsed. In Hungary the difficult parts insofar as I could make out from my in-laws were earning enough to buy a vehicle (very hard) and that the cars were only built after they had been ordered (hence the delay of a few weeks or months). I can't image it was that different in the USSR -- except in a child's imagination or a parent's exaggeration of how crappy things were in the past. (Side note: many elderly miss the Communist era.)

Comment: Also worth raising is that the author is from Lithuania. If memory serves me well the USSR was rather oppressive with the three Baltic countries. But I'm not familiar enough with Russian or Lithuanian history to suggest whether this might have impacted car delivery delays in those area.

Comment: @Denis de Bernardy I did live in Soviet Union and can confirm "10 year" waitlist for cars, or at least that's what my parents said. I do not think you had to pay until you picked it up.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy That is not really a reliable indicator: what was there status, what kind of car: imported, new or *used?* With connections things speed up and used cars could be sold and bought to any- and everyone's pleasure. Luck? For all I know, most people ordering a newly made Eastern car had to wait quite a bit. From vague memory estimated, probably the least for a Polsky Fiat?

Comment: @LаngLаngС: New cars, eastern made, and fairly well off on both sides insofar as I'm aware. Whichever it is, though, please come back with an actual source. I'm referencing first-hand sources (a 70 year old father in law, and an 85 year old grand mother in law). You're merely citing "from vague memory". And Bald Bear seems to be citing whatever his parents may have exaggerated. I'm simply not buying it that it took 5-10 years except in Reagan's fantasies. I can build a car faster than that in my garage.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Well WP says so (unsourced) for [USSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automotive_industry_in_the_Soviet_Union), [and](https://www.zeit.de/1973/19/rueckwaerts) [GDR](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verf%C3%BCgbarkeit_von_PKW_in_der_DDR) as well. It's only "vague" as I don't have any hard stats at hand now.Oh except this [GDR-thing: min12–max17](http://www.ddr-geschichte.de/GESELLSCHAFT/Verkehr/Fahrzeuge/Privatauto/privatauto.html)

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Thank you. So, per the German GDR article you cite, and reading between the lines, it's a bit of both. It was "more than a year" of delay around 1965, which is in line with what I've heard about from my in-laws. The 10+ years waiting time appears to have occurred indeed, but in the decade before the USSR's collapse -- when demand far outstripped supply.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Well, Hungary is perhaps another matter altogether, I have data for [GDR, Romania and USSR](https://books.google.com/books?id=o6MCBQAAQBAJ) and some imprecise Polish data (plus an impression of late 70s vastly 'improving' on that front — FFF would have been delighted over these deterrent conditions…). For GDR & USSR it was almost the entire time quite 'long' a wait (the +12months after early 60s only buffered by min buying power, mean car age 12 years in 70s). Then the 'bloc' was [less blocky than often thought?](https://books.google.com/books?id=2dt4AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT67&lpg=PT67)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy you may believe my recollection, that the GDR, Hungary and even the Baltic states had quite different standards of living (in the better direction), compared to the "heart" of the USSR. My uncle had a car in the USSR without waiting, but he bought it from someone else, not from an "official dealer". 10 years or so were the "common" way, without "connections", extra money etc.

Comment: @BaldBear you didn't have to pay upfront (generally at least), you just had to have money, wait and hope "the people's" government wouldn't pass a "currency reform" at the time you were waiting.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy *The 10+ years waiting time appears to have occurred indeed, but in the decade before the USSR's collapse -- when demand far outstripped supply* the time before it it must have been simply because the government didn't print "enough" money, so people simply didn't even bother to apply for the line for a car. I suspect there definitely was a link between "the demand outpacing the supply" and the "currency reform" of 1990, when they simply nullified high-denomination bills.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Party members got their new cars (Skoda for example) earlier than regular folks in East Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Car insurance (and other private property insurance) existed, and was mandatory. The only difference in this respect with capitalist countries was that the insurance company belonged to the state, and there was no choice of insurance company, and no competition between them.